# create slider frame specific link?

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, slider

Is it possible to link a particular frame of a slide?
For example, I have a slider with frames 1,2 & 3.
Is it possible to create links by clicking on which I can display Frame 1/2/3 of a the slider.
Also please note that the link will be in a separate page.

Page 1,
Link1 - Takes us to Frame1 of Slider in page 2

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very simple keep your slider frame/ image within hyperlink tag or with onclick function like:

```
<li><img src="images/ban-small01.png" alt="" title="" onclick="hello()" /></li>
```